# How to get process id in the method called by activiti:expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activiti

We are using Activiti to build our Workflow and all of its tasks is defined as ServiceTask. Currently, all of the tasks uses activiti:expression shown as below:

```
activiti:expression="${etcx.runThis('first variable','second variable')}"
```

Now, what we want to achieve is to obtain the process id of which this caller ServiceTask belongs to. To be more precise, it would be like calling the etcx.runThis('first variable','second variable','processid') in all ServiceTask. But, we think this would be a bit clumsy process because the users of our workflow have to add processid manually. How can we get currently running processid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem and successfully obtained the workflow ID with the following:

```
String workflowID = Context.getExecutionContext().getProcessDefinition().getId();
```